# setTimeout and scrollTop animation on click not working in accordion

Tags: jquery, settimeout, scrolltop

I would the active/expanded accordion item to jump to the top when clicked. This position changes as the accordions have not finished sliding open or closed resulting in an offset.

I have learned that I need to wrap this function in setTimeout so it executes after the sliding animation is complete. Here is my code so far

```
$('.accordion-title').on('click', function() {
var content = $(this).next();

$('.accordion-content').not(content).slideUp(400);
$('.accordion-title').not(this).removeClass('expanded');
$(this).toggleClass('expanded');
content.slideToggle(400);
        
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 100);

});
```

I have tried the below but it results in an error

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 100);
},400);
```

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3p6c5ku/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need the this code ?

```
$('.accordion-title').on('click', function() {
    var content = $(this).next();

    $('.accordion-content').not(content).slideUp(400);
    $('.accordion-title').not(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    
    var self = this;
    content.slideToggle(400, function(e) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(self).offset().top}, 100); 
    });
    
   

});
```

Comment: Thank you mate that works well, I can see why it wasn’t working